# ERROR: ERROR: Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Service; exception=Class not found: io.kubern

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am getting below error for jenkins pipeline.

Jenkins version    : 2.249.3
kubectl version :
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.5", GitCommit:"e6503f8d8f769ace2f338794c914a96fc335df0f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-06-26T03:47:41Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.12", GitCommit:"7cd5e9086de8ae25d6a1514d0c87bac67ca4a481", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-11-12T09:11:15Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

All plugins : Latest version

Loading configuration: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my-kub-tester/test-kube.yml
ERROR: ERROR: Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Service; exception=Class not found: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Service
in 'reader', line 1, column 1:
kind: Service
^

hudson.remoting.ProxyException: Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Service; exception=Class not found: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Service
in 'reader', line 1, column 1:
kind: Service
^

```
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:335)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObjectNoCheck(BaseConstructor.java:229)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:219)
at io.kubernetes.client.util.Yaml$CustomConstructor.constructObject(Yaml.java:337)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructDocument(BaseConstructor.java:173)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:157)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:490)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadAs(Yaml.java:456)
at io.kubernetes.client.util.Yaml.loadAs(Yaml.java:224)
at io.kubernetes.client.util.Yaml.modelMapper(Yaml.java:494)
at io.kubernetes.client.util.Yaml.loadAll(Yaml.java:272)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.wrapper.KubernetesClientWrapper.apply(KubernetesClientWrapper.java:236)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.command.DeploymentCommand$DeploymentTask.doCall(DeploymentCommand.java:172)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.command.DeploymentCommand$DeploymentTask.call(DeploymentCommand.java:124)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.command.DeploymentCommand$DeploymentTask.call(DeploymentCommand.java:106)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1163)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.command.DeploymentCommand.execute(DeploymentCommand.java:68)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.command.DeploymentCommand.execute(DeploymentCommand.java:45)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.CommandService.runCommand(CommandService.java:88)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.CommandService.execute(CommandService.java:96)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.CommandService.executeCommands(CommandService.java:75)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.BaseCommandContext.executeCommands(BaseCommandContext.java:77)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.KubernetesDeploy.perform(KubernetesDeploy.java:42)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.SimpleBuildStepExecution.run(SimpleBuildStepExecution.java:54)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.SimpleBuildStepExecution.run(SimpleBuildStepExecution.java:35)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Caused by: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: Class not found: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Service
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor.getClassForNode(Constructor.java:664)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.getConstructor(Constructor.java:322)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:331)

Comment: Try downgrading recommendations from https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-cd-plugin/issues/134

Comment: @SameerNaik Thanks. I followed below steps it worked for me. Downgrade Jackson 2 API to v2.10.3 and Snakeyaml API to v1.26.2

Comment: great, Let me post it as answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading recommendations from github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-cd-plugin/issues/134

Answer (score 0):

This is related with two jenkins plugins with bugs. Downgrade snakeyaml-api and jackson2-api  and it will work just fine.